# Force PyGtk main to redraw

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, gobject

I have a UI structure like this:
1x HorizontalBox -> 8x VerticalBox -> 2x Section(GObject) -> 1x RectangleWidget(gtk.DrawingArea)

This simply is a table of 16 cairo rectangles in two rows.

The cairo rectangle widget itself is a subclass of gtk.DrawingArea and has an expose-handler.

I now rewrote the program, the data structure and the UI now are completely separated. There is a thread running in the background, updating the data structures. In fornt of the UI `gobject.threads_init()` is called. After a timeout of 100ms `gobject.timeout_add(100, self.update_widget)` the main emits a signal, which is only received by the first widget.

Here the expose-handler:

```
def OnDraw(self, widget, event):    
    # self.window / widget.window works both
    ctx = widget.window.cairo_create()
    ctx.save()

    rect = self.get_allocation()    
    ctx.rectangle(50, 0,  30, rect.height)
    ctx.set_source_rgb(*self._BACKGROUND_RGB)
    ctx.fill()

    ctx.rectangle(0, rect.height * (1. - self.section.GetLevel()), rect.width, rect.height)
    ctx.clip()        
    ctx.set_source_surface(self.source, 0, 0)   
    ctx.paint()
    ctx.restore()

    return False
#_____________________________________________________________________

def update_widget(self):
    rect = self.get_allocation()        
    self.window.invalidate_rect(rect, False)
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration(False)
    return True
#_____________________________________________________________________
```

note:
If I minimize and restore the window, the widgets receive the gsignal and get updated.

I have tried different approaches. Including threading, different signaling... All approaches lead to the same behavior described above.

How can I force the gtk.main to return and redraw the other widgets?

Answer (score 2):

Try `mainHbox.queue_draw()`

If it didn't work, iterate over all RectangleWidget objects and redraw:

```
for vbox in mainHbox.get_children():
    for hbox in vbox.get_children():
        for widget in hbox.get_children():
            widget.queue_draw()
```

And if you are using a `Table`, that's even easier...

Answer (score 0):

> After a timeout of 100ms gobject.timeout_add(100, self.update_widget)

Try to make GUI thread without gobject.timeout_add() and all other calculation in another thread[s].

gobject.timeout_add looks like separated thread and gtk can`t work with it normally.

Part of my program (it works):

```
def init_tr_modules(self):
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.set_title("Checking internet connection")
    window.set_border_width(2)
    window.set_icon(app_gui.icon)
    window.set_geometry_hints(None, 510, 27)
    vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 1)
    vbox.set_border_width(1)
    window.add(vbox)
    pbar = gtk.ProgressBar()
    vbox.pack_start(pbar, False, False, 1)
    window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    window.set_resizable(False)
    pbar.set_text("Wait")
    pbar.set_pulse_step(0.01)
    window.show_all()
    tr_thread = \
         threading.Thread(target = self.init_tr_services)
    tr_thread.start()
    while self.queue.qsize() == 0:
        while gtk.events_pending():
            gtk.main_iteration(False)
        pbar.pulse()
        sleep(0.05)
    while self.queue.qsize():
        self.queue.get()
    window.set_title("Get list")
    pbar.set_fraction(0.005)
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration(False)
    for i in self.tr_services:
        pbar.set_text(i.service.get_service_name())
        tr_thread = \
            threading.Thread(target = i.service.renew_list)
        tr_thread.start()
        while self.queue.qsize() == 0:
            while gtk.events_pending():
                gtk.main_iteration(False)
        while self.queue.qsize():
            self.queue.get()
        new_val = pbar.get_fraction() + (1.0-0.006) / len(self.tr_services)
        pbar.set_fraction(new_val)
    window.destroy()
#end def
```

All non-gui actions hided in non-main thread. Main thread - gui.
Hope this helps if I understand question properly. :)